# Income Tax on per Diem (Non Accountable plan)

Tags: united-states, income-tax, tax-deduction, irs

My Employer started giving me per diem @ of  4.50 per hour, the per diem pay check runs separately and it includes Medicare and Social related taxes, but no Federal or State tax. The pay check list the total amount as taxable wages. So does this means that the per diem amount will be included in the AGI on W2 and **I need to pay taxes on it**.If yes then, **Can I itemize it** ?

Comment: This sounds very unusual.  "Per diem" is a reimbursement for travel expenses, and is paid "per day," not "per hour."  You wouldn't normally pay any taxes on it, unless the amounts exceeded the [per diem guidelines](http://www.gsa.gov/portal/category/104711) published by the IRS.  Can you confirm that your employer is actually reimbursing you for travel expenses on a per hour basis?

Comment: As Ben says ... "The pay check list the total amount as taxable wages" it's simply not a "per diem".  "per diem" is very simply "expenses".  So, for convenience you buy a camera or something on behalf of the office, as there was no money in the petty cash draw, and they of course give you back the $200.  That has no connection to income or taxes.  What you describe here is simply *not* expenses ("The pay check list the total amount as taxable wages").  "per diem" is just another term for "expenses".

Answer (score 1):

A per diem payment is a cost of doing business for the company, not for you. They can claim it (probably); you can't (definitely).

Comment: Supporting reference?

Comment: Per diem is supposed to be reimbursement for your incidental expenses while traveling. That's what it's budgeted as by the company.  That's why they don't withhold tax on it; it isn't salary, it's their cost. You don't generally get taxed on it but you can't write it off either.

Comment: ... Supporting reference? ;)